# Connect tranformer and a toroidal one?

Tags: transformer

I want to upgrade components on my state amplifier. 
And adding another transformer might be the biggest change.
Is it be possible to connect in parallel a normal tranformer and a toroidal one for the same current without too many risks?

Comment: No. Horrible things will happen. Did you mean that you want to *replace* the existing transformer with a toroidal transformer? Why do you think another transformer will help?

Comment: There is little risk if you don't attempt to apply power. Otherwise, no it will not be a result you want to see, hear or smell.

Comment: What is a "state amplifier", anyway?

Comment: Solid State Amplifier also known as a Transistor Stereo Audio Amplifier.

Comment: I know what is a "*solid* state amplifier". I still don't know what is a "state amplifier".

Answer (score 1):

There is ZERO potential benefit from augmenting (or replacing) the power transformer (assuming that is what you are talking about?)

And there are HUGE potential problems from trying to do this.

Nobody knows WHY you think doing anything with the power transformer will have ANY benefit at all?  It seems preposterous.

Comment: Not a constructive answer

Comment: It is not a "constructive" question, either.

Comment: From what I read. It seems that increasing power in an stereo amplifier along with other changes (capacitor, retifier, etc.) will decrease the audible noise(humming sound) at a certain volume. But I might be wrong.

Comment: No. Increasing the power of a stereo amplifier will make audible noise (like hum) even louder.  If you are trying to solve a problem with hum, modifying or changing the amplifier is NOT the solution.

Comment: If your hum is coming from the power supply, you need a cleaner or more intelligently regulated power supply, but not necessarily 'bigger'.

Comment: If I were to obtain a tighter and cleaner bass, without changing speakers, would a quality improved recap might be the best solution then?

Comment: No. It sounds like you are just shooting a shotgun in complete darkness.  Re-capping the power amplifier would not be on the top-5 list of things you could to improve bass response.

Comment: Top 5? Could you please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Power transformers in parallel need to have the same *Short Circuit Voltage* (called Vsc or Uk). That voltage is a measure how "soft" a transformer is. When one transformer is "softer" than the other, under load its output voltage will decrease more than that of the other, what results in a balancing current flowing between them.

So, no: you cannot parallel an EI core and a toroidal core transformer.

And even when Uk is similar enough, you have to consider it when calculating the power distribution between the transformers. You cannot simply add it.

Here's an example calculation I once wrote up, it parallels two transformers with different Uk (Vsc).

$$S = 900\ \text{kVA}$$
$$S_\text{n1} = 400\ \text{kVA,}\ u_\text{k1} = 8\ \%$$
$$S_\text{n2} = 600\ \text{kVA,}\ u_\text{k2} = 6\ \%$$

$$u_\text{k} = \frac{\sum S_\text{n}}{\sum \frac{S_\text{n}}{u_\text{k}}} = \frac {1000\ \text{kVA}} {\frac {400 \text{kVA}} 8\ \% + \frac {600 \text{kVA}} 6\ \%} = 6,67\ \%$$

$$S_\text{1} = S \cdot \frac{S_\text{n1}}{\sum S_\text{n}} \cdot \frac{u_\text{k}}{u_\text{k1}} = 900\ \text{kVA} \cdot \frac{400\ \text{kVA}}{(400\ \text{kVA} + 600\ \text{kVA})} \cdot \frac{6,67\ \%}{8\ \%} = 300\ \text{kVA}$$

$$S_\text{2} = S \cdot \frac{S_\text{n2}}{\sum S_\text{n}} \cdot \frac{u_\text{k}}{u_\text{k2}} = 900\ \text{kVA} \cdot \frac{600\ \text{kVA}}{(400\ \text{kVA} + 600\ \text{kVA})} \cdot \frac{6,67\ \%}{6\ \%} = 600\ \text{kVA}$$

See how the "softer" 8% Uk transformer 1 cannot be loaded to its rated power without overloading the "harder" 6% Uk transformer 2.

Comment: Being diferent core will never match each other.Thank you for a simple answer that I could not find anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In most amplifier of two channels, I.e. stereo amps,,there will be only one transformer supplying power to both sides. If its an OEM design, surely the transformer is already properly rated for the stated maximum output power of the amplifier.

If the amplifier is self made and your existing single transformer is under rated for two channels rated output power then it seems the idea of adding another transformer is valid,,but not in electrical parallel to the existing one (unless they both are guaranteed exact same type).

The second transformer if not exact same type, keep its secondary separated. Rectify its output into dc using another set of rectifier and also separate reservoir caps. This dc must be supplied separately to the second channel power amp circuitry.

This mod will make the amp more powerful provided output transistors are heat sinker adequately.

Comment: I´ve seen paralell transformers on modified diy ampifiers but they add to be preciselly the same and needed some adjustment using capacitors and even a bridge rectifier?? I didn´t know it was possible use them in separatly for each chanel.Thx

Comment: Its perfectly possible to power them from two separate DC source and the only shared link is the starred common ground. But the amps must be modular, much better if the amps sits on separated PCBs.